# What is the working mechanism for current increase with voltage increase (in case of a capacitor)

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance

Image I have a loaded parallel-plate capacitor having capacity $C$ with a fixed charge $Q$ on the plates. It induces a voltage $U = Q / C$.  If I connect a load with resistence $R$, then a current $I = U / R$ begins to flow.

Now, imagine I move the plates apart while retaining the charge. This reduces the capacity, but as the charge is fixed, the voltage increases as well. This makes totally sense as I have to perform work to move the plates, i.e., move a charge against the electrical field between the plates, which, basically, is the definition of voltage.

So, when connecting the load after moving the plates a higher current begins to flow.

What I do not understand is how to think about what is happening here on an atomic level. Why is more current flowing. Basically, the electric field is only inside the capacitor. The particles in the wire that connects the load see only the charges at the ends. These charges push (or pull at the other end) the particles. However, the amount of charge is the same in both scenarios, so why do we have a larger current in the second case? Where does the additional force comes from?

Comment: Think about it this way, you have two finite size opposite charges very close to each other, they will hit each other with certain speed, Now pull these two apart to a longer distance apart and observe, now you will see these will hit each other with larger velocities. Capacitor is doing the similar thing but with a different mechanism

Comment: I see, but they seem to be reaching their terminal velocity (=drift velocity) quite fast, right, i.e., no extended period of acceleration? So that the additional energy stored in the velocity can be used in the load. In this sense the resistance is like the "(air) drag". By the way, this would imply that if the plates are moved very far apart the field that initially acts on the charges gets weaker, up to a point that the terminal velocity is reached later and we have a noticable acceleration. This would imply that the energy output at a load before the terminal velocity is smaller [...]

Comment: [...] than predicted by $I = U / R$. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field **isn't** only inside the capacitor: there's a potential difference, and thus a field, between the wires that connect it to the resistor. There's the same potential difference across the resistor, and thus a field internal to the resistor. The charge and capacitance of the capacitor control that potential difference.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. But what is about the typical "textbook" argument that the field outside the plates is zero? Why does it not apply here?